# MongoDB update nested array of object by index

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Let's suppose to there is db like below...

```
{ _id: 1234,
  key: 'Contacts',
  value: [
     { name: 'McDonald', phone: '1111'}, 
     { name: 'KFC', phone: '2222'}
  ]
}
```

And I want to change KFC's phone number to '3333'.

What I did is

```
DB.findOne({ key: 'Contacts' }, function(err, db){

        db.value[1]['phone'] = '3333'
        db.save(function(err, result){ 
            // done 
        })
    }
)
```

But it didn't update the database. What am I wrong?

---

1. There's no specific _id in elements of array for some reason.
2. Only the way to find specific element is `index`.

Comment: Have you tried using `findAndUpdateOne()`?

Comment: @JohnKennedy How can I access to nested object from `findOneAndUpdate`? I don't know how to...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the positional operator $

more info : [https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#up.*S*](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#up._S_)

```
DB.update({key: "Contacts", "value.name": "KFC" },
         { $set: { "value.$.phone" : 666 } },function(err,doc){

         });
```

Comment: Thanks, it works,! I should have used some specific key for this. Thanks.